# Is this a correct solution to this problem? 2018 AIME II Problem 10

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

Problem:

Find the number of functions $f(x)$ from $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ to $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ that satisfy $f(f(x)) = f(f(f(x)))$ for all $x$ in $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.

Solution:

Note that there are $5^5$ possible functions $f(x)$.

Now consider the probability of picking a function from those $3125$ functions that satisfies, exclusively, one of the following criteria:

$P(x = f(x) = f(f(x)) = f(f(f(x)))) = \frac{1}{5^5}$

$P(x \neq{f(x)} = f(f(x)) = f(f(f(x)))) = \frac{1}{5^4}$

$P(x = f(x) \neq{f(f(x))} = f(f(f(x)))) = \frac{1}{5^2}$

$P(x \neq{f(x)} \neq{f(f(x))} = f(f(f(x)))) = \frac{1}{5}$

Thus the number of functions $f(x)$ satisfying the condition stated in the problem is given by:

$\frac{5^5}{5^5} + \frac{5^5}{5^4} + \frac{5^5}{5^2} + \frac{5^5}{5} = 1 + 5 + 125 + 625 = \boxed{756}$.

Comment: Why can't a function satisfy $x = f(x) $ for some $x$ and $x \ne f(x) = f(f(x))$ for others?

Comment: Well it could, but each of the probabilities listed above is taken to mean "f(x) satisfies these conditions for all $x$ in the domain." I'm not sure I quite understand what your question is getting at though.

Comment: A function that does what I suggest would not be counted in your total.

Comment: I don't understand your calculations.  A brute-force count with a python script gave me $1791$.  I can't guarantee the correctness.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Is that not desired, since we want $f(x) = f(f(x))$ for ALL $x$? The function you mention—one in which the condition given in the problem statement is satisfied only in part—can freely be thrown out. Or am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: @saulspatz There are other solutions posted on the page: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2018_AIME_II_Problems/Problem_10. So $756$ is indeed the correct answer. I'm wondering if this particular solution, which appears cleaner than the rest, is actually sound. It seems like it would require multiple unlikely coincidences for it to be incorrect, but I can't determine why it works.

Comment: For example, one solution is $f(1)=1, f(2)=2, f(3)=3, f(4)=1, f(5)=4$.  This satisfies $x=f(x)$ for $x=1,2,3$, $x\ne f(x)=f(f(x))$ for $x=4$, and $x \ne f(x) \ne f(f(x)) = f(f(f(x)))$ for $x=5$.  Where does it fall in your list?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Then $f(x)$ satisfies, for all values of $x$ in the domain, only $f(f(x)) = f(f(f(x)))$. So I believe it would fall under the last case, if we take $\neq$ to be "not equal for every value of $x$."

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I thought is said $f^{(2)}=f^{(4)}$, not  $f^{(2)}=f^{(3)}$.  Corrected script gets $756$.

Comment: $x = f(x) \neq f(f(x)) $  I thought $x=f(x)$ means that $f$ is the identity, but then so is $f\circ f$.

Comment: So how do you get those probabilities?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I was trying to extrapolate from the fact that there's one function satisfying the first case, namely $f(x) = x$, and five satisfying the second, namely $f(x) = k$ for each of $k = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$. The others were more of an intuition / guess about the number of functions satisfying more restrictive conditions. I was wondering if the original intuition there made sense, and I was also curious about why there happen to be four cases here and 756 is a sum of four powers of 5.

Comment: @saulspatz Rats, you're right. Still wondering why there are four cases and the answer happens be a sum of almost-consecutive powers of five, for a question asking about functions over a set of five elements. Plus, the first two numbers in that sum are definitely correct, I believe. Seems like it would be too big of a coincidence if it were false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  We are told that $f(x)=x$ on $f^2(S) = \{f(f(s)): s \in S\}$.  On the other hand, if $f(x)=x$ then $x = f(f(x)) \in f^2(S)$. Now $f^2(S) \subseteq f(S) \subseteq S$.
If $f(S) = S$, then $f^2(S) = S$ as well, and $f(x)=x$ for all $x$.
If not, $f$ maps $S \backslash f(S)$ into $f(S)$, and maps $f(S) \backslash f(f(S))$ into $f(f(S))$.  Each point of $f(S) \backslash f(f(S))$ is the image of a point of $S \backslash f(S)$.  There are the following possibilities for cardinalities of $S \backslash f(S)$, $f(S) \backslash f(f(S))$, and $f(f(S))$:

- $0,0,5$
- $1,0,4$
- $1,1,3$
- $2,0,3$
- $2,1,2$
- $2,2,1$
- $3,0,2$
- $3,1,1$

You can then compute the number of possibilities in each case.
For example, for the case $2,2,1$, there are $5!/(2!2!1!)= 30$ ways to choose which points go in which set, then $2$ ways to map the two points of $S \backslash f(S)$ to $f(S) \backslash f(f(S))$, and only one way to do the rest (both points of $f(S) \backslash S$ must map to the one point of $f(f(S))$, and that point maps to itself), so $30 \times 2 = 60$ functions corresponding to this case.

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to one of the solutions posted on the website. Would you be able to verify whether what's stated in the solution I gave is true, or is that not feasible? For example, I know the first case is true, but I'm wondering how to check the fourth.